# can I run ansible playbook on ec2 just with ssh keyfile no aws key/pair?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-2.x

If I don't have an AWS key pair nor permissions to create/delete EC2 instances but just access to one instances thru SSH with an `keypair.pem`, can I still just use Ansible to setup my server?

As I don't have access to all EC2 instances, can I just not use boto/aws keypair at all and just add this unique EC2 instance I have access in the inventory file?

I tried this on my inventory file:

```
[aws_server]
aws_instance ansible_host='MY_EC2_INSTANCE.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' ansible_user='ubuntu' ansible_ssh_private_key_file='/myproject/testkey.pem'
```

But not able to connect with `ansible-playbook -i inventory site.yml`:

```
fatal: [aws_instance]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.", "unreachable": true}
```

PS: I can run `ssh -i testkey.pem ubuntu@MY_EC2_INSTANCE.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com` without problems

Comment: Your setup seems to be ok. Run playbook with `-vvvv` to check the error. Or even enable `ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1` to get the most verbose output to get the actual error.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was happening because I was using the AWS hostname instead of IP and for some reason it was "too long". How did I discover it? As suggested by users from #ansible IRC channel, I ran it with `-vvvv`to get full log and was able to see the SSH command that was giving the error.

```
ansible-playbook  -vvvv -i inventory site.yml
```

I tried running the SSH command Ansible ran with the same options plus `-vvvv` and the last lines of the log before it fails were:

```
debug1: setting up multiplex master socket
debug3: muxserver_listen: temporary control path /Users/vmenezes/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-MY_EC2_INSTANCE.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com-22-ubuntu.NSUADT9KwyIpvhWi
unix_listener: "/path/to/my/project/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-MY_EC2_INSTANCE.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com-22-ubuntu.NSUADT9KwyIpvhWi" too long for Unix domain socket
```

and as you can see the last line clearly says `too long for Unix domain socket`. I don't know exactly why this limitation as it is indeed a valid URL but changing for the IP address solved problem.

Something to keep in mind, when everything fails, `-vvvv` is really helpful to see what is happening under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

The key pair should be enough to allow you to connect with your EC2 instance. I've just tried it with my setup and it seems to be working.

Have you tried using the full path to the keypair in question? For me it did the trick.

Comment: Yes, I added the full path but still the same error. What version of Ansible are you using? I'm on 2.1.1.0 and I'm seeing 2.x has few differences

Comment: I'm on 2.1.0 so probably the same syntax should work fine. I can see another difference between your host file and mine - try changing `ansible_user` to `ansible_ssh_user` and `ansible_host` to `ansible_ssh_host`

Comment: thanks but still didn't work (and actually it would surprise me as ansible_ssh_user and ssh_host were deprecated on 2.x http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html)

Comment: Could be you're right, I did set up this hostfile a long time ago, and it might have still been an earlier version. Anyway works for me so that syntax is still valid, even if deprecated.
Can you try adding your own key (id_rsa.pub) to the servers authorized_keys file and see if you can use that to connect? It will help you differentiate between problems with ansible and problems with the key.